# WPF TreeView Disable Children Selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking for a way to disable a built in action of the WPF TreeView. In WPF, when you select a parent node of a TreeView, it also selects all children nodes in that group. I don't want this. What I want is a single selection. Here is an image showing what is currently happening:

[image]

Again, what I am wanting is to only select single rows.

Here is the XAML that I'm currently using:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="VoidwalkerTreeView" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        Background="{DynamicResource Voidwalker_Brush_ContextArea}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ScrollViewer
                            Padding="4"
                            CanContentScroll="False"
                            Focusable="False">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid
                        Width="15"
                        Height="13"
                        Background="Transparent">
                        <Path
                            x:Name="Collapsed"
                            Margin="1,1,1,1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"
                            Fill="{DynamicResource Voidwalker_Brush_ActiveTextForeground}" />
                        <Path
                            x:Name="Expanded"
                            Margin="1,1,1,1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Data="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"
                            Fill="{DynamicResource Voidwalker_Brush_ActiveTextForeground}"
                            Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Collapsed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Expanded" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                            Opacity="0"
                            Stroke="Black"
                            StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                            StrokeThickness="5" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Voidwalker_Brush_ActiveTextForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Grid x:Name="itemGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="19" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ToggleButton
                            x:Name="Expander"
                            ClickMode="Press"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" />
                        <Border
                            x:Name="Bd"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="PART_Header"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsPresenter
                            x:Name="ItemsHost"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="itemGrid" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="itemGrid" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Does anyone know how to change this XAML, or point me in the correct direction as to how I can allow only single row selection? A good example of the desired behavior is how Visual Studio treats it's solution treeview. You can only do single selection, unless you deliberately hold down shift or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `IsSelected` trigger for the `TreeViewItem` style, you are changing the background colour of `itemGrid`. `itemGrid` contains everything - the header *and* child items. Try targeting to something more specific (e.g. the border `Bd`):

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you.